# Spring MVC, how to have a controller handler handle all the requests before the mapped handlers?

Tags: spring, interceptor, httpsession

I've wrote a web app with its brave controllers and handler mapping, everything with Spring 3.0 and controller annotations. Now turns out that I need simple and custom autentication. I don't want to use ACEGI for the moment, because I've no time to learn it. I'd like ideally that I could have a routine that gets called before every mapped handler, gets from the HttpSession the userId, checks if he is logged in and the session key and if not redirects to a login page. I've been thinking about an interceptor... the problem is that you have to use HandlerInterceptorAdapter, which has the following method:

```
 public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {
```

that won't let me access the HttpSession associated with the request. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure? You should be able to obtain the session through `request.getSession()`.

Comment: sure, why not? That session belongs to that particular user who makes the request. The session may or may not exist depending on whether you create one for this user or not, but otherwise this is how HTTP session works in general. I'm not sure what you meant by "safe".

Comment: I mean with threads and everything. I'm using  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" p:synchronizeOnSession="true" />
 to have thread safe httpsession objects. is this ok?